# Pandas CParseError, file downloaded via FTP

Tags: python, pandas, ftp, ftplib

I am trying to read a csv file (downloaded via FTP )in Pandas using read_csv

```
df = pandas.read_csv("file.csv")
```

but I get error :

```
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at line 652
```

The code to download the file via FTP:

```
f = open(file_name, 'wb')
ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + file_name, f.write)
```

But when I download the same file on browser and parse it, it does fine. Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('ftp://...')  # puth there the real FTP URL
```

from [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

> **filepath_or_buffer** : str, pathlib.
>
> Path, py._path.local.LocalPath or any object with a read() method (such as a file handle or StringIO)
>
> **The string could be a URL. Valid URL schemes include http, ftp**,
> s3, and file.
>
> For file URLs, a host is expected. For instance, a local
> file could be file ://localhost/path/to/table.csv

Comment: Thanks Max , it worked like a charm. I will accept this as an answer once the SO's time limit is over.

Comment: @dealerkam, glad I could help :)